# Compare build results in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, functional-testing, cicd

First and foremost, maybe what I am looking for isn’t possible or I am going down the wrong path.

We've a process of running Functional Test suits (in Jenkins) for every PR before merging it with master. Once FT Job succeeds, we are manually comparing the results with the baseline results (kind of hard copy we maintained separately). I am looking to automate the process of matching the results with baseline results and notify if any discrepancy,

For Eg, Build #1 result is baseline result, and every other build (in the same job) should be compared with Build #1 and share the report.

Comment: The content you are comparing, what is it? A log file or xml or Json. When you are saying you do manual comparison, do you look for functional correctness or identical out put ?

Comment: You can pull the console from the previous jobs using the REST API then use regex to filter and compare as needed

Comment: @Ram I'm trying to compare the result counts. Say No of total cases, Passed, Failure counts against the baseline build.

Comment: If you are using Junit or any test framework that creates a Junit compatible XML then you can use the Junit plugin from Jenkins ‘ def summary= junit testResults: “***/**/TEST\*.xml”’ this summary object now has pass,fail count which you can compare with your baseline. *Summary.passCount, summary.failCount, summary.totalCount, summary.skipCount*

Comment: As far as getting the numbers from build1 into others, you can create a file in a shared location or archive the file in the build and use the artifacts in others. I think there are multiple ways which you can use for that.

Comment: @Ram Thank You! Can you explain bit more in getting the results from other build in Jenkins (Aside from Shared location option)

Comment: I answered the question. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Are you trying to compare test code coverage results between PR and baseline results?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that there are 2 parts to this question

- Running the baseline build and storing and fetching the test results
- Running a feature branch build and comparing the test results against the baseline

My below answer is on an assumption that you are using a [multi-branch pipeline](https://devopscube.com/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-tutorial/) setup.

**Part 1**

Run the baseline project build and I assume you are running it as a dedicated branch. Let us assume it as a branch `baseLine`.
After running tests in the baseline branch, use JUnit plugin to report the results to Jenkins

`junit testResults:'**/TEST*.xml'`

**Part 2**

Run your feature branch `feature1` pipeline.

After the tests, report the results using the JUnit plugin

`def featureTestResults = junit testResults:'**/TEST*.xml'`

Fetch the results from the base-line (You may have to work on authentication part here)

```
sh """ 
wget -O baseLine.json https://<Jenkins-server>/job/<Project-NAME>/job/baseLine/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/json -H "Accept: application/json" 
"""
```

Now read the json into an object

`def baseLineTestResults = readJSON file: "baseLine.json"`

Now compare the two results

```
boolean resultsMatched = false
if(featureTestResults.passCount == baseLineTestResults.passCount && featureTestResults.failCount == baseLineTestResults.failCount && featureTestResults.skipCount == baseLineTestResults.skipCount) {
   resultsMatched = true
}
```